# How can I prevent duplication in event listener in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

For some reason the amount of 1's duplicates every time a category is chosen. If the oneBtn is clicked, I want there to only be a single 1 added to the text field per click. In other words, for each time the category is changed (thisOne or thatOne), another 1 is strung along when the oneBtn is clicked. so if the category is changed twice, the oneBtn will input 11 per click. I would like to understand why this is happening and if it can be remedied in vanilla js.

My guess is that somewhere there is a count of clicks being storing away  and maybe that's whats affecting the outcome. If thats true, is there a way to reset this count to zero for each time a catgory is changed to prevent the duplication? I might be way off, i'm just guessing here.

```js
/*GET MEAL CATEGORY ITEMS*/
  let thisOne = document.getElementById('thisOne');
  let thatOne = document.getElementById('thatOne');
  
function addOne(x){
    /*GET OPTION ITEMS*/
      let oneBtn = document.getElementById('oneBtn');
      let inputText = document.getElementById('inputText');

    /*FUNCTION TO CHANGE CATEGORY HEADER*/
      let changeHeader = () => {
        let header = document.getElementById('header');
        header.innerHTML = x.target.innerHTML;
       }; changeHeader();

    /*FUNCTION TO ADD 1 TO TEXTFIELD*/
      let addInput = (x) => {
        inputText.value += x.target.innerHTML;
       } 
    oneBtn.addEventListener('click', addInput);
};

thisOne.addEventListener('click', addOne);
thatOne.addEventListener('click', addOne);
```

```html
<h1>Choose category</h1>
<button class="category" id="thisOne">thisOne</button>
<button class="category" id="thatOne">thatOne</button>
<br /><br />

<div>
<h3 id="header"></h3>
  <input id="inputText" type="textfield" /><br /><br />
    <button id="oneBtn">1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You are appending a string, not adding a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you click on thisOne thatOne you attach another eventListener to the oneBtn. So all the eventListeners are executed one after the other.

Move the eventListener outside of the addOne function and it should work as expected.